# Attribute to Check Auth Logic in .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

The stack is latest .NET Core w/ C#.

We are pasting the same code checking if someone is trying to edit their own profile (we have their `profileId` from a JWT) into almost every controller:

```
if (User.GetProfileId() != profileId)
  return Unauthorized();
```

I am at a bit of a loss how to remove this redundancy. I can definitely add generic middleware or a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to perform this, but it seems heavy handed. Is there some approach to add a `[MustOwnProfile]` attribute and have .NET Core run the test in the above code anywhere the attribute appears?

An example of the above check  in context:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{profileId:int}/start-profile/{checklistId:int}")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StartProfile(int profileId, int checklistId)
    {
      if (User.GetProfileId() != profileId)
        return Unauthorized();

      await _profileService.StartProfile(profileId, checklistId);
      return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming an authorized user only can edit own profile, then I think 'User.IsAuthenticated())' should be enough for this check.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define custom attributes.
[Cancellation and short-circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cancellation-and-short-circuiting)